# force push via a pr possible? Want to rewrite history

Tags: git, git-flow, git-filter-branch

I have a repo with thousands of commits of garbage binaries. I am using git extensions plugin to locate the large files and its commits. We are using git flow with PRs only to Develop and Master. 
I would like to confirm this is/will be the best way to clean up this repo.

```
git reset --hard
git pull develop
git checkout -b CleanUpRepo
```

run the plugin that is more or less a nice git filter branch (its instructions are reset, choose files to delete, force push)
once the clean up is done I commit the changes

```
git add .    
git commit -m "removed a ton of files" 
git push -f
```

Now I should have a decent origin branch that I can just PR through to develop and master branches? Is this the correct way to do this? I would assume this will correctly rewrite history? We have tons of rogue origin branches that people have branched off master etc over time. 
I don't understand git well enough to be able to proceed with confidence on this. 
I checked into what the plugin does and it seems to do the following (im assuming the params are hashes or filenames etc) more focused on the commands:

```
 "{0}\" filter-branch --index-filter \"git rm -r -f --cached --ignore-unmatch {1}\" --prune-empty -- --all"
 for /f %%a IN ('\"{0}\" for-each-ref --format=%%^(refname^) 
 refs/original/') DO \"{0}\" update-ref -d %%a",
 \"{0}\" reflog expire --expire=now --all",
 "\"{0}\" gc --aggressive --prune=now",
```

Comment: In Git (locally on your computer), `pull` means *fetch and merge* (or *fetch and rebase* if you configure it to mean that). A *pull request* is not really something Git has, it's something offered by web hosting sites like GitHub and Bitbucket and each one has their own special features around this added thing, but most of them wind up doing a merge. A merge *doesn't* rewrite history, so for most hosting services, you *cannot* rewrite history through a pull request.

Comment: What system used? GitHub? Tfs? Gitlab? Etc. Cloud or on premise?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get a one-time permission to push to master and overwrite the whole repo.  This will push new versions of all tags, it will change the branch pointer for all users of the repo (and subsequently break all forks and outstanding pull-requests.

A Pull Request pulls in a specific branch from one repo into another, but won't clean up the data in existing branches. Plus it will try to merge the contents into the old branch and create a mess. If you choose rebase instead of merge, the pull request will be blocked as the PR can't be rebased on the current head.

Depending on the hosting platform, all of the commits you removed will still exist in the remote repo, as they aren't removed from the remote server (Azure Repos for example). The only way to solve that is to delete/rename the repo and then push the cleaned contents into a fresh repo.

In the past I used the [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) for these situation. It sounds friendlier than the tool you've used.